# How to move a 3D projectile Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, projectile

I am trying to understand the process for creating a 3D projectile in Unity. Of the few online posts about creating a regular, laser-like projectile, there is very little explanation about the process. Can someone please help me understand like a step-by-step methodology of how to approach shooting a projectile.

Problem I am trying to understand:

- How to move the projectile in the direction that the shooter GameObject is facing. Using the position.Translate() method forces me to pick a specific direction to move the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to move the projectile in the direction that the shooter
>   GameObject is facing

You use the Camera's `Transform.forward`  to make the projectile travel towards the position the player is facing.

The Process of shooting a projectile is as below:

**1**.Instantiate/Create Bullet

**2**.Set position of the bullet in front of the player

**3**.Get the `Rigidbody` that is attached to that instantiated bullet

**4**.
*If this is just Camera with Character Controller and no visible gun*,

Shoot the Bullet with `Camera.main.Transform.Position.forward` + `shootSpeed` variable.

*If there is a visible Gun or Object you want to shoot from*,

create another GameObject(ShootingTipPoint) that will be used as the place the bullet should shoot from and position it in the location Gun or Object you want to shoot from, then you use that GameObject's `ShootingTipPoint.Transform.Position.forward`  to shoot the bullet instead of `Camara.Main.Transform.Position.forward`.

And a working code for this:

```
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public float shootSpeed = 300;

Transform cameraTransform;

void Start()
{
    cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
}

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        shootBullet();
    }
}
void shootBullet()
{
    GameObject tempObj;
    //Instantiate/Create Bullet

    tempObj = Instantiate(bulletPrefab) as GameObject;

    //Set position  of the bullet in front of the player
    tempObj.transform.position = transform.position + cameraTransform.forward;

    //Get the Rigidbody that is attached to that instantiated bullet
    Rigidbody projectile = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    //Shoot the Bullet 
    projectile.velocity = cameraTransform.forward * shootSpeed;
}
```

Comment: Why don´t you just instantiate a Rigidbody right away? You could just create the projectiles with a rigidbody as prefab. Pass it as a parameter to your script.